# Is there an Excel VBA function to resize text to fit a shape?

Tags: excel, vba, autosize, text-size

I am drawing circles in excel with a number in them, but as soon as that number hits a double digit, the second digit is not visible.

I would like the textsize to fit the shape.

I cannot change the size of the circle, because this is based on the opportunity value.

I am working on a business funnel, the relevant input of the funnel is:
- ticket number
- value of opportunity (potential revenue): used to size the circle

The circles are drawn in the funnel, which exists of four stages that are depicted as four shapes.

I have tried:

```
Public Function DrawCircle(x As Integer, y As Integer, tickets As Collection, ticketIndex As Integer)

    Dim myCircle As Shape

    Dim circleSize As Integer
    circleSize = GetTicketSize(tickets, ticketIndex)

    Dim name As String
    name = "" & tickets.Item(ticketIndex).id

    Set myCircle = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Graphic funnel").Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeOval, x, y, circleSize, circleSize)
    myCircle.Select
    Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.Visible = msoTrue
    Selection.ShapeRange.TextFrame.Characters.Text = name
    Selection.ShapeRange.Left = Selection.ShapeRange.Left
    Selection.ShapeRange.Top = Selection.ShapeRange.Top - circleSize / 2

    With myCircle
        .DeleteText
        .wrapformat = msoWrapFormat
        .WordWrap = True
        .AutoSize = msoAutoSizeTextToFitShape
    End With
```

But it returns: "object doesn't support this property or method"

Comment: Which line throws the error?

Comment: Most likely the `.autosize...`. second to last

Comment: You could look at the lenght of the string and set the text size to a fixed value depending on the size. So one digit values get size X, two digits get Z, and so on.

Comment: Try 2 fontsize less than what you are using now. So if you are using font 12 right now then use font 10. That ways whether it is single digit or double digit, the numbers will fit?

Comment: Is it not .DeleteText causing the error ?